# Getting a 301 error when trying to php curl

Tags: php, curl

For the first time I've become desperate enough about an issue to actually sign up here. I'm trying to write a webservice with curl so others can upload some info to my server. I have no influence on the code of my "customers" and hence the url they call must must muuuust be http://..../update

However, this results in a "301 - permanently moved" error until I add a / at the end. Just adding a / would be a simple enough solution if it wasn't for the fact I cannot change the url. In other words, it has to work without the /

My support team suggested I try to put a redirect in my .htaccess and I did that and it does add the / at the end, but I still get the 301. This is in the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    /
RewriteRule    ^update$  update/  [R]
```

so, this is the code that calls:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$ch=curl_init();
$url="http://www.virtualairlines.eu/update";
$cleaned_params='(some xml)';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $cleaned_params);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
echo $ret;
```

as you can see I tried to use followlocation but that removes the posted data and presents me with an empty page.

this is the code that receives it: (the index.php in the update folder)

```
$data= urldecode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
```

(there is some more code but it isn't relevant)

Once I put the final / in the url above, everything works. 
Again, I have no influence on the sending end other than testing things at my own machine. 
Any takers?

Comment: This might help you:
https://serverfault.com/questions/250161/how-do-i-remove-trailing-slashes-from-a-url-when-using-apaches-default-director

If not, could you add the content of your .htaccess too ?

Comment: Just to point out, a 301 redirect ins't an error, it is just telling you that the content for that URL is in a different location. If you add a redirect to your `.htaccess` file your are creating the redirect.

Comment: well its an erroneous error because the content is actually there. I really don't understand why the webserver makes such a fuss about the trailing slash, and I don't understand the sollution posted on serverfault.com. I updated the post to include the .htaccess but currently disabled it again as it doesn't do anything anyway.